# How to keep list centered in nav between three images?

Tags: html, css

In my navigation bar, I have the logo on the far left and two flags on the far right (for english/italian). I understand that the UL is a block element, and so the two flags get pushed down to the next line, however, the UL does center between the right border of the navbar and the logo on the left.

When I change the display to inline-block of the UL, the flags come up, but the UL is not centered anymore-- hoping maybe someone has some suggestions. I was thinking of maybe creating the navbar without a list?

How can I make the UL center based on the position of the three images?

Thanks for your help.

https://jsfiddle.net/p9hgmetf/

```css
   nav {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-top: 0px;
     z-index: 2;
     width: 1200px;
     height: 80px;
     line-height: 40px;
     background: #222;
     color: white;
     padding: 0 1%;
   }
   nav ul {
     margin-left: 1%;
     list-style-type: none;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
     display: inline;
   }
   nav ul li {
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
   }
   nav ul li a:link,
   nav ul li a:visited {
     color: #FFF;
     border-bottom: none;
     font-weight: bold;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 110px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
   }
   nav ul li a:hover,
   nav ul li a:active {
     opacity: .6;
   }
   nav ul li.selected {
     background-color: rgba(184, 140, 199, .8);
   }
   #logo {
     margin-top: 5px;
     float: left;
     display: inline-block;
   }
   #en {
     margin-top: 0px;
     display: inline-block;
     float: right;
   }
   #it {
     float: right;
     margin-top: 0px;
     display: inline-block;
   }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="../index.html">
    <img src="../images/sblogo.png" alt="Logo" img id="logo">
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li class="selected"><a href="home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="news.php">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="artist.html">The Artist</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="../it/home.html">
    <img src="../images/italian.jpg" alt="Cambio Lingua in Italiano" img id="it">
  </a>
  <a href="../en/home.html">
    <img src="../images/eng.jpg" alt="Change Language to English" img id="en">
  </a>
</nav>
```

Comment: Without positioining one or more of the elements this is very difficult. Perhaps flexbox, I'd have to think.

Comment: Like 'text-align: center' on your nav?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you would place the logo at the beginning of the nav and the languages at the end of the nav. The main navigation (ul element) on the center between logo and languages (with the same space on left and right).

Here my solution to solve this:

```css
.logo {
  align-self:flex-start;
}
.nav {
  align-self:center;
}
.languages {
  align-self:flex-end;
}
nav {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  margin-top: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 1200px; 
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background: #222;
  color: white;
  padding:0 1%;
}
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
  display: inline;

}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
}
nav ul li a:link,
nav ul li a:visited {
  color: #FFF;
  border-bottom: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav ul li a:hover,
nav ul li a:active {
  opacity: .6;
}
nav ul li.selected {
  background-color: rgba(184,140,199,.8);
}
#logo {
  margin-top:5px;
  float:left;
  display: inline-block;
}  
#en {
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
}
#it {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="../index.html">
      <img src="../images/sblogo.png" alt= "Logo" img id="logo">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <ul>
      <li class="selected"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="artist.html">The Artist</a></li>
      <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="languages">
    <a href="../it/home.html">
      <img src="../images/italian.jpg" alt= "Cambio Lingua in Italiano" img id="it">
    </a>
    <a href="../en/home.html">
      <img src="../images/eng.jpg" alt= "Change Language to English" img id="en">
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Additional you have to remove `margin-left: 1%;` from `nav ul` in your CSS.

A working fiddle you can find here: https://jsfiddle.net/sebastianbrosch/p9hgmetf/1/

Comment: Thank you! But, how come in firefox, the 'contact' tab goes down to a new line?

Comment: I updated my answer: "Additional you have to remove `margin-left: 1%;` from `nav ul` in your CSS."

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flexbox` to achieve what you're after...

```css
nav {
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-top: 0px;
     z-index: 2;
     width: 1200px;
     height: 80px;
     line-height: 40px;
     background: #222;
     color: white;
     padding: 0 1%;
     display: flex; /* DISPLAY: FLEX; */
    justify-content: center; /* JUSTIFY CONTENT, HORIZONTAL CENTER */
  align-items: center; /* ALIGN ITEMS TO THE VERTICAL CENTER*/
   }
   nav ul {
     margin-left: 1%;
     list-style-type: none;
     text-align: center;
     padding: 5px 0px 5px 0px;
   }
   nav ul li {
     flex-grow: 1; /* STRETCH THE ITEMS TO NICELY FILL THE SPACE */
     display: inline-block;
     padding: 5px 0;
   }
   nav ul li a:link,
   nav ul li a:visited {
     color: #FFF;
     border-bottom: none;
     font-weight: bold;
     display: inline-block;
     width: 110px;
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
   }
   nav ul li a:hover,
   nav ul li a:active {
     opacity: .6;
   }
   nav ul li.selected {
     background-color: rgba(184, 140, 199, .8);
   }
   #logo {
     margin-top: 5px;
     float: left;
     display: inline-block;
   }
   #en {
     margin-top: 0px;
     display: inline-block;
     float: right;
   }
   #it {
     float: right;
     margin-top: 0px;
     display: inline-block;
   }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="../index.html">
    <img src="../images/sblogo.png" alt="Logo" img id="logo">
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li class="selected"><a href="home.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="news.php">News</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="artist.html">The Artist</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <a href="../it/home.html">
    <img src="../images/italian.jpg" alt="Cambio Lingua in Italiano" img id="it">
  </a>
  <a href="../en/home.html">
    <img src="../images/eng.jpg" alt="Change Language to English" img id="en">
  </a>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox should do the trick. Below is the key CSS rules you'll need (plus I resized some things so you can see the result better). The `justify-content` rule indicates how the content within the nav should be distributed. See [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a really good overview of the CSS flexbox model.

```css
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
<a href="../index.html">
<img src="../images/sblogo.png" alt= "Logo" img id="logo">      </a>
<ul>
  <li class="selected"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="artist.html">The Artist</a></li>
  <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
<a href="../it/home.html">
   <img src="../images/italian.jpg" alt= "Cambio Lingua in Italiano" img   id="it"></a>
<a href="../en/home.html">
    <img src="../images/eng.jpg" alt= "Change Language to English" img id="en"></a>
   </nav>
```

Another approach would be the following. This tells the ul to grow as much as it can, pushing the other elements to the side.

```
nav {
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  flex: 1;
}
```